# How to set a global _ttl in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my setup I have a central syslog server, which forwards all of its logs to node with elasticsearch through td-agent (fluentd). I will post the configuration at the end.

Now, everything works nicely, I can search through the logs, I was able to make a cluster of elastichsearch nodes and so on. What I need to have now is to set _ttl of all incomming documents. I want them to be deleted after 30 days.

I tried to

```
curl -XPUT 'http://172.19.19.225:9200/fluentd' -d '{ "tweet" : { "_ttl" : { "enabled" : true, "default" : "2h" }}}'
```

(yes, I was that stupid, that I let the 'tweet' there), but of course it did not work and now every other try gives me

```
{"error":"IndexAlreadyExistsException[[fluentd] already exists]","status":400}
```

and I dont know what to do anymore.

Iam open to all solutions, thanks ^^

/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf:

```
<source> #Input plugins are defined be <source>...</source> statements
  type syslog #This is the Syslog input plugin, which we will use later in this tutorial
  port 42185
  tag es.syslog
</source>

#<source>
#  type http #This is the HTTP input plugin, which turns Fluentd into an HTTP endpoint
#  port 8888 #Send data to http://localhost:8888/<Fluentd tag>?json=<json event>
#</source>

<match es.**>
  type copy
  <store>
    type elasticsearch
    logstash_format true
    index_name fluentd
    type_name fluentd
    flush_interval 3 # For testing
    host localhost
    port 9200
  </store>
#  <store>
#    type stdout
#  </store>
</match>
```

Elastic search is in default configuration. Directory with indices looks like this:
ls /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices:

```
fluentd          logstash-2014.02.13  logstash-2014.02.16  logstash-2014.02.19  logstash-2014.02.22  logstash-2014.02.25  logstash-2014.02.28  logstash-2014.03.03  logstash-2014.03.06  logstash-2014.03.09  logstash-2014.03.12
kibana-int       logstash-2014.02.14  logstash-2014.02.17  logstash-2014.02.20  logstash-2014.02.23  logstash-2014.02.26  logstash-2014.03.01  logstash-2014.03.04  logstash-2014.03.07  logstash-2014.03.10  logstash-2014.03.13
logstash-2014.02.12  logstash-2014.02.15  logstash-2014.02.18  logstash-2014.02.21  logstash-2014.02.24  logstash-2014.02.27  logstash-2014.03.02  logstash-2014.03.05  logstash-2014.03.08  logstash-2014.03.11  logstash-2014.03.14
```

Comment: Do you ve any problem with re-indexing???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Close the index first:**

```
      $ curl -X POST 'http://172.19.19.225:9200/fluentd/_close'
```

**update the settings**

```
      $ curl -X PUT 'http://172.19.19.225:9200/thegame/_settings' -d \
     '{ "tweet" : { "_ttl" : { "enabled" : true, "default" : "30d" }}}'
```

If it again throws the error.Then you need to delete the index and recreate the index with ttl value of 30d

**DELETE an index**

```
      $ curl -X DELETE 'http://172.19.19.225:9200/fluentd/'
```

**Create an index**

```
      $ curl -X PUT 'http://172.19.19.225:9200/thegame'
```

**Update mapping**

```
      $ curl -X PUT 'http://172.19.19.225:9200/thegame/_settings' -d \
      '{ "tweet" : { "_ttl" : { "enabled" : true, "default" : "30d" }}}'
```

HOpe it helps..!